# Network computer shutdown unless a specific process is running

Tags: windows, batch

I wish to create a batch file to shutdown a list of computers on my network.
That's easy enough with psshutdown from PSTools or even the regular shutdown command.

My problem is that I wish for the script to verify if a certain process is running on the remote computer and if it is, don't shutdown that computer.

For example if remotepc001 is running notepad.exe, don't shut it down.

Does anyone know of a good way to do that?

Comment: You could check processes (and run the shutdown) remotely using PowerShell... Or you can use PsList (part of PsTools).

Comment: Can you help me phrase it in an IF statement?

Comment: Sorry, I was on my phone. I'll write up a full answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tasklist` (built-in) or `PsList` (part of PsTools). Both support remote computers. My example will be using `tasklist` (who doesn't like built-ins?) on a local computer, as that is all I have to test on at the moment. You can add the correct arguments to connect to a remote computer; check the available arguments with `tasklist /?`.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq processname.exe" | find /I "processname.exe"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto NotRunning else goto Running

:NotRunning
echo The program is not running.

goto :eof

:Running
echo The program is running.

goto :eof
```

#### Breakdown:

`tasklist` is used to list all process that match the specified name. You can use wildcards (`*`) to do partial matches.

`find` is used to check if the process name was part of the `tasklist` output. It will set the `errorlevel` (basically, the return value) to 1 (failed) if it is not found, otherwise 0 (succeeded). This is used because it's easier to check the errorlevel than the text output of `tasklist` when in an `if`.

We then use `goto` to jump to the correct block, thereby separating execution depending on if the process is running or not. You could also just run the commands within the `if` statement. `goto :eof` basically means go to the end of the program (EOF = End Of File), i.e. exit.